# Check if midi input or destination is open

Tags: audiokit

It's easy to open midi inputs inputs with AudioKit:

```
AudioKit.midi.openInput(name)
```

And close:

```
AudioKit.midi.closeInput(name)
```

Can't find any way to check if a input or destination is open

Comment: Good point, I think we've just been relying on the developers to manage this for themselves.